# Azure Website Deployment from Visual Studio - How to deploy just a single missing assembly?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

I have an Azure website built using Visual Studio and .NET (C#). I noticed that for whatever reason, an assembly was not getting put into the /Bin folder when BS built the app. So I copied the file to my Bin folder. However, when I deploy, the file I manually copied to the /Bin folder isn't getting included in the deployment. Or at least I don't think it is.

Is there a way I can tell VS to include this file when I publish? Or is there a way I can tell VS to republish the entire app, instead of just files it detects are changed?

Comment: Copy that DLL to one folder and add reference of from it

Comment: Have you tried setting "Copy local" to "true" in that reference?

Comment: This has been happening sporadically for me - and only when publishing to a deployment slot. If I mess around with the 'Precompile before publishing' settings enough, it will EVENTUALLY publish the DLL successfully. But it's an unpredictable PITA in the meantime. (CopyLocal is always true.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For managed assemblies, setting `CopyLocal` to true for the reference fixes it.

If it's an unmanaged binary, then you can follow following approach:

- Look for `AfterBuild` on the `.csproj` file, and include a command to copy the binary to `bin` directory.

  ```
  <Message Text="Copy $(SolutionDir)Lib\binary.dll to $(OutDir)binary.dll" Importance="high"/>
  <Copy SourceFiles="$(SolutionDir)Lib\binary.dll" DestinationFiles="$(OutDir)binary.dll" />
  ```
- Include the binary on the `.csproj` along with other files. Setting visible to  false will hide the file on Solution Explorer.

  ```
  <Content Include="Bin\binary.dll">
    <Visible>false</Visible>
  </Content>
  ```